# How to restrict player movement using Mathf.Clamp()?

Tags: unity-game-engine, monodevelop

HI I am making a game where player has to control a cube. Cube moves on x axis. Using Horizontal input axis. The problem I am facing with is that I don't want the cube to go out from the screen. I tried using Mathf.Clamp() function to clamp the movement but It doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerControls : MonoBehaviour
{
    float xMovement;
    [SerializeField] private  float movingSpeed = 5f;
    [SerializeField] private float xRange = 5f;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        movement();
    }

    private void movement()
    {
        float clampedXpos = Mathf.Clamp(xMovement, -xRange, xRange);
        xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        transform.Translate(clampedXpos * movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[GetAxis](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Input.GetAxis.html) returns a value in the range of -1 and 1. You clamp the previous frames xMovement between -5 and 5 **not** the player's global position!

```csharp
private void movement()
{
  xMovement = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
  float newXpos = transform.position.x + xMovement * movingSpeed * Time.deltaTime;
  float clampedXpos = Mathf.Clamp(newXpos, -xRange, xRange);
  
  transform.position = new Vector3(clampedXpos, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);
}
```

This code is essentially a splits up `Transform.Translate` equivalent. This is necessary, so that the clamp can be applied at the right time.

`Translate` works by adding your axis delta values to the current position and "teleporting" the transform to the newly calculated spot. You already calculate the correct frame-rate independent delta, so that's just copied. Since only the x-axis is clamped we only calculate the `newXposition`.

Before "teleporting" the transform we need to make sure that it stays in bounds by clamping. If we assume that your previous position was 4.8f and the x-delta is 0.3f. Their sum and the newXposition would be 5.1f (which would be out of bounds), however the clamp will limit it to 5.

Being posetive that our `clampedXpos` is legal, we can finally teleport the transform to the right spot. For this we need to pass the 3 axis as a new vector. `clampedXpos` for the x-axis and the transforms old positions for the y and z-axis.

Comment: Hi Thank you so much. Can you tell me the logic behind this? as I am a beginner it would help me learn this. Also please tell me why we didn't use Transform.translate